# MinHeight property makes datagrid and listview of different sizes

Tags: wpf, listview, grid-layout

```
<Grid x:Name="LstGrid" Margin="5">
   <ListView 
      x:Name="dataGroupList" 
      Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=LstGrid}" 
      Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=LstGrid}" 
      MinWidth="340" 
      MinHeight="250" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding DataCollection}"/>
</Grid>
```

While inspecting though snoop,I found-the Actual Height of Grid is 248 whereas the Actual Height of ListView is 250 in this case. If I remove the MinHeight , the height of Grid and ListView comes out to be same. I want the heights to be same in case of MinHeight as well.There is difference of two units between the two heights or the two widths when minHeight and minwidth properties are set.Kindly explain the why minheight produces the difference and how can I fix this.

```
<Grid x:Name="LstGrid" Margin="5" MinHeight="260">
   <ListView 
      x:Name="dataGroupList" 
      Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=LstGrid}" 
      Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=LstGrid}" 
      MinWidth="340" 
      MinHeight="250" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding DataCollection}"/>
</Grid>
```

I tried by forcing the minHeight of grid to be greater than ListView.Now, the Actual Height comes out to be same 
but the desiredSize has again a difference of 2 units. So how to make the two heights same?

Comment: Not sure I understand your problem but `MinHeight` takes priority and for example when window is less the 250 then `Grid` won't grow beyond that but `ListView` still pushes 250 minimum height hence it will be bigger then `Grid` and partially hidden. If you remove `MinHeight` then `ListView` will grow only as much as `Grid` allows

Comment: @dkozl: Any work around with minHeight, as I need it for my layout.??